# Running a C program with an unknown amount of arguments

Tags: bash

For example, If i have a program and I want to run it with every .txt file in the current directory, but I want these to be used at the same time

```
./program file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ........... fileX.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $(find -type f); do
    if [[ "$filename" == *".txt"* ]]; then
        ./program $filename
    fi
done
```

Currently I have something like this which works for each file, but I'm not sure how I can make it do it for all the files in one command.

```
./program x y z
```

for an unknown amount

Thanks!

Comment: try `for filename in *txt`

Comment: You can simply do `./program *.txt`